# How can new members persist when pushing to a Vec in a for loop?

Tags: rust

I am trying to learn how to utilize objects in Rust by hacking away. The following code predictably gives "borrowed value does not live long enough" but I'm not sure what to change. What is the approach to creating a bunch of instances in a for loop that can then be access outside of it?

```
let mut vec_ducks: Vec<&Duck> = vec![];

for i in 0..100 {
    let _x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 100);
    let _y = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 100);

    let duck = Duck { x: _x, y: _y };

    vec_ducks.push(&duck);

    //println!("{}", i);
}

for d in &vec_ducks {
    d.quack();
}
```

Comment: *why* are you taking a reference to `duck`?

Comment: "creating a bunch of instances in a for loop that can then be access[ed] outside of it" - isn't it exactly what the borrow checker trying to _prevent_?

Comment: "Trying to learn OOP", Rust isn't usually considered an OOP language though.

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm working from: https://stevedonovan.github.io/rust-gentle-intro/object-orientation.html#object-orientation-in-rust

Comment: @prismspecs that resource seems to be geared at teaching Rust to people coming from an OOP background; if you are trying to *learn* OOP, I don’t know this is a good route.

Comment: Is this a Rust tutorial that never talks about lifetimes and owning values?

Comment: @Shepmaster to be more clear, I mean that I am trying to learn how to utilize objects in Rust, specifically.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what types, methods, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that when you create `duck` it is inside the block of for loop causing it to exist as long as the for loop exists, to fix this you need to *transfer* ownership of `duck` to the `vec_ducks`.

In your code:

```rust
let mut vec_ducks: Vec<&Duck> = vec![];

for i in 0..100 {

    let _x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 100); 
    let _y = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 100); 

    let duck = Duck{x:_x,y:_y}; // duck is created here

    vec_ducks.push(&duck);

    //println!("{}", i);
} // duck is dropped or out of scope here

for d in &vec_ducks { // you try to use values of duck here, where they no longer exist
    d.quack();
}
```

Change the code to:

```rust
// take Duck and not a reference to it
let mut vec_ducks: Vec<Duck> = vec![];

for i in 0..100 {

    let _x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 100); 
    let _y = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 100); 

    let duck = Duck{x:_x,y:_y};

    // move ownership
    vec_ducks.push(duck);

    //println!("{}", i);
}

for d in &vec_ducks {
    d.quack();
}
```

Further more the example in [gentle introduction](https://stevedonovan.github.io/rust-gentle-intro/object-orientation.html#animals) works because `duck1` and `duck2` are in the same scope/block as `ducks` i.e. the main block.

You can read more about ownership and lifetimes [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ownership.html) and [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html)